# How to disable JSON OK responses (but not errors) in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In a ASP.NET Core 3.1 API I need to be strict with content negotiation. If actions are executed OK, the response will have a `application/pdf` content-type, but if there are any errors (eg a 400, 406, etc) the content-type will be `application/problem+json`.

The relevant part of my Startup class is:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
            options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new PdfOutputFormatter());
        });
```

In my controller:

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    [ApiController]
    [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
    public abstract class PdfController : ControllerBase
    {
```

The requests with an `Accept: application/json` and `Accept: text/json` returns a `200 OK` but a `406 Not Accepted` is expected.

I tried removing the JSON output formatter with:

```
options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType(typeof(SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter));
```

But this makes all errors (for example a `400 Bad Request` with a `application/problem+json` content type) return a `406 Not Accepted` as there is no output formatter for JSON responses.

**How can I remove the ability to send JSON responses (ie `Accept: application/json` → `406`) without breaking the ability to send `application/problem+json` responses for errors?**

Comment: The built-in mechanisms for content negotiation in .NET Core are completely wack. We've stopped using them on my team entirely because of how backwards it works. I suggest to anyone doing content negotiation in .NET Core to just roll their own middleware or ActionFilter to handle content negotiation and forego the awful built-in mechanism for it. What ultimately made us switch was that you could send a complete junk header, the system would do all the work associated with the request, and only when returning responses would it actually check the content type and return 406 or not.

Comment: Meaning you have to roll back all the changes from the request because it defers this check to when its preparing the response. The side-effects that this resulted in gave us massive headaches until we figured out this deficiency in the design. Its completely half-baked. Rolling your own solution is pretty trivial and will save you a lot of headaches.